# Is there a way to resolve a service without routeProvider?

Tags: angularjs

I have a controller that it's not defined on `$routeProvider`. I use it internally inside other controllers. Is there a way to resolve a dependency without the `$routeProvider`?

==

My friend below asked for more information, here it goes:

I don't want to call promise methods (basically `then`) inside my controllers. But I have dependencies on some of this controllers that are promises. When a controller is defined on the $routeProvider, I can `resolve` its dependencies. But how about the controllers that are not defined there? Is there any solution? Follows an example:

My $routeProvider doesn't map this controller and this is the code I have to do because my `Cart` is a promise:

```
.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'Cart',
  function ($scope, Cart) {
    Cart.then(function(res) {
      $scope.cart = res.query();
    });
```

This is the code I'd like to do:

```
.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'Cart',
  function ($scope, Cart) {
    $scope.cart = Cart.query();
  });
```

Comment: need to do a better job providing question details if you want answers

Comment: There it is charlietfl :)

Comment: you wanted to solve a problem that initially fixes a problem. I mean a promise does this basically because it solves a problem. you might need to find something that ain't a promise.

Comment: @Noypi, yeah, I know it solves a problem. But as I said, there's that solution when you declare your controller on $routeProvider and you can resolve the dependencies before it is called. I just wanted to know if there was other way to do the same thing (resolve dependencies) but out of the scope of $routeProvider configuration. Thanks!

Comment: ahhh, i think you wanted to execute the promise once. you can use $controller service to instantiate your controller.

Comment: if that solves your problem, i can show you a sample.

Answer (score 0):

if you mean resolve -- dependency injection -- yes. below should work:

```
element.injector().invoke(['dep1','dep2', function(dep1,dep2){}])
```

...
the idea is to retrieve the current injector, and use invoke().

Comment: Hey, I updated my question with more infos. The way that you say is not what I'm looking for. I'd prefer call the promise method on this case. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: that's ok, i enjoy answering questions anyways... even if my answer is just far out, hehe...